Kubernetes error when creating replicaset application
I tried to create replicaset application file in the terminal but ends up with an error saying Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "replicaset-definition.yaml": ReplicaSet in version "v1" cannot be handled as a ReplicaSet: strict decoding error: unknown field "replicas", unknown field "selector". Can anyone help me fix this issue? Thanks
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: myapp-replicaset
  labels:
      app: myapp
      type: front-end

spec:
  template:

    metadata:
     name: myapp-pod
     labels:
        app: myapp
        type: front-end
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-container
        image: nginx

replicas: 3
selector:
   matchLabels:
      type: front-end


(You don't typically directly create a ReplicaSet.  Do you mean a Deployment instead?)

The issue is in the wrong indentations. The template, replicas, and selector fields should be on the same indentation level. In your case, it should looks like:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: myapp-replicaset
  labels:
      app: myapp
      type: front-end

spec:
  template:

    metadata:
     name: myapp-pod
     labels:
        app: myapp
        type: front-end
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-container
        image: nginx

  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      type: front-end

You can use one of the k8s syntax validation tools—for example, Kubeval—for checking YAML files for these kind of issues:
Alexanders-MacBook-Pro:~ alexander$ kubeval tst.yaml
PASS - tst.yaml contains a valid ReplicaSet (myapp-replicaset)

